# Create a menu like in Firebug

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I try to develop my Firefox addon and I would like to have a menu similar to Firebug, a menu-button with a picture. Here is what I mean:

[image: screenshot]

I tried to set the image attribute, with CSS but the picture is never displayed.

Anyone have an idea or an example?

Comment: To see that I want [here](https://twitter.com/#!/Sadlig/status/180267000872976386/photo/1/large)

Comment: So, what *exactly* did you try? Firebug uses a regular `<toolbarbutton type="menu-button">` and sets the image via `list-style-image` CSS property.

Comment: Thanks it was exactly that I want

Answer (score 2):

The MDN page on [menu-button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/MenuButtons#The_%27menu-button%27_button) has an example that should work for you in an overlay.  Here is an adaptation that could be inserted into your overlay (with the style suggestion from Wladimir):

```
<toolbarbutton type="menu-button" label="" style="list-style-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico')">
  <menupopup>
    <menuitem label="Save This Document"/>
    <menuitem label="Save All" oncommand="alert('Save All'); event.stopPropagation();"/>
  </menupopup>
</toolbarbutton>
```